# Avoid qrcode cloning

Tags: security, qr-code

I was doing an app that reads qrcodes, and I was wondering how can I avoid that anyone with a qrcode generator could clone one of my qrcode.

I know I can't avoid the duplication (especially if you use a small number) but I was wondering if there is any approach I could use to reduce this or add an app validation to avoid this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a one-time-use id where the first person to access your URL wins, or just accept it as free advertising. If you really wanted to go to the trouble I guess you could probably print a watermark that obscures the code so it is unreadable, somewhat like the security features most checks have, but this really sounds like an XY problem.

Think about the problem you're really trying to solve and how so solve it. QR codes themselves are just as reproducible as emailing someone a link or giving someone a piece of paper with a word on it.

Comment: I was thinking in the case that a qrcode identify a user of the system, like if it was a credit card. Obviously in the Credit card the add a password. But what if you don't want to add one (for speed and simplicity) it's there any way the system could handle that case? I guess not but perhaps there is a way